# Changing overlaying labels text on a ScrollView

Tags: ios, scrollview, label, updating

This is sort of hard to explain so I'm including a picture.

[image]

So I have a scrollview (the yellow part) and then an overlaying box with score and how many upgrades the player purchased, etc. The green box with the labels stays in the same position while the yellow part scrolls. That works fine, except I am trying to get the labels to change when the player purchases an item. So lets say the player purchases a pickaxe. The upgrades owned should change from "0/20" to "1/20".

This is my setup. I am using SpriteBuilder by the way. I have a class that handles the scrollview, like the buy buttons and descriptions, etc... Then I have another class just for the overlay on the side, and this is basically the only method in it:

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    if (_doge < 1000000000000) {
        balanceLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2Lf", _doge];
    } else {
        balanceLabel.string = @"A lot!";
    }
    upOwnedLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _upOwned];
    upMaxedLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _upMaxed];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _upOwned]);
}
```

I've tried a few things and this is the one that I think is "most correct". In the didLoadFromCCB on the scroll class, I have this:

```
UpgradesScene *upgradesScene = [[UpgradesScene alloc] init];
[upgradesScene didLoadFromCCB];
```

It's in the correct place (under buy button) but for some reason it doesn't update the label. I do get an NSLog message telling me the level, but for some reason the label doesn't work.

I'm very new to this language so please go easy on me :) Thank you

Comment: Did you check whether object is nil or not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating a new upgradesScene with alloc init rather than getting a reference to the one that's in your scroll view. You should have a property (or IBOutlet if you're making this in IB) that points to that view.